# How to transform PagingData<T> into model in collectLatest() in UI

Tags: android-livedata, kotlin-flow, android-paging-3, kotlin-android

I am having a situation, where once I get `pagingData <T: UIModel>`, I need to get additional data from a different API. The second Api requires arguments that are there in first API response.  Currently I am collecting in UI Layer in `lifecyclescope` as,

```
            loadResults().collectLatest {

                PagingResultAdapter.submitData(lifecycle, it)
               
                // Extracting the data inside PagingData and setting in viewmodel.
                it.map { uiModel -> 
                    Timber.e("Getting data inside map function..")
                    viewModel.setFinalResults(uiModel)
                }
            }
        }
```

**But the problem is, the `map{}` function on pagingData won't run during data fetching**. List is populated, ui is showing the items in recyclerview. But the map function not running..(I am not able see the log)

The UI layer `loadResults()` function in-turn calls the `viewmodel.loadResults()` with UI level variables. In terms of paging everything is working fine, but I cannot transform the pagingdata into UIModel in any layer.
Official site suggests to use `map{}` function only.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-transform#basic-transformations

B**ut I am not getting at which layer I should apply `map{}` and also before collecting or after collecting..Any help is good..**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PagingData.map` is a lazy transformation that runs during collection when you call `.submitData(pagingData)`. Since you are only submitting the original un-transformed `PagingData` your `.map` transform will never run.

You should apply the `.map` to the `PagingData` you will actually end up submitting in order to have it run. Usually this is done from the `ViewModel`, so that the results are also cached in case you end up in a config change or cached scenario like when navigating between fragments.

You didn't share your ViewModel / place you are creating your Pager, but assuming this happens at a different layer you would have something like:

MyViewModel.kt

```
fun loadResults() = Pager(...) { ... }
  .flow
  .map {
    Timber.e("Getting data inside map function..")
    setFinalResults(uiModel)
    it
  }
  .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

MyUi.kt

```
viewModel.loadResults().collectLatest {
  pagingDataAdapter.submitData(it)
}
```

NOTE: You should use the suspending version of `.submitData` since you are using Flow / Coroutines, because it is able to propagate cancellation direction instead of relying on launched job + eager cancellation via the non-suspending version. There shouldn't be any visible impact, but it is more performant.

Comment: Yeah..applying ```map{}``` on paging data is to be done in ViewModel only and also before I call ```cachedIn()```. But when I was trying the same in VM, with setFinalResults(uiModel), the function was only setting the ViewModel property and returning ```Kotlin.Unit```. So for the downstream, I got only ```PagingData<Unit>```.

Comment: So finally, I am applying ```map{}``` as you said in VM and before ```cachedIn()``` call only. But my ```setFinalResults()``` function is now returning UIModel and the downstream also getting the ```PagingData<UIModel>```.

Comment: Ah map actually transforms the item, so you need to return the original item if all you care about it the side effect. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah..now it is more convincing...

Comment: cant call map block in pager

Comment: @RezaZavareh sorry, didn't see this until now - I was missing the property access for `Flow<PagingData>`. The .map is Flow's .map operator. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
import androidx.paging.map

.flow.map { item ->    
    item.map { it.yourTransformation() }
}
```